# What are the differences between load angular dependencies and what is the best way to share modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, bower, multiple-domains

What is the difference between those ways of load modules?

```
angular.module('CoreApp', ['...','...','...','...']); //parent module
angular.module('MainApp1', ['CoreApp']);  //child 1
angular.module('MainApp2', ['CoreApp']);  //child 2

angular.module('CoreApp', ['...','...','...','...','MainApp1','MainApp2']); //parent module
angular.module('MainApp1', []);  //child 1
angular.module('MainApp2', []);  //child 2
```

...
Apart from that, maybe I'm doing it wrong. My mainApps are going to run in different domains(mainapp1.com and mainapp2.com). I have some headers(login,menus) and footers that i want to share it instead of copying and changing them on each module. Of course i have directives and services(such a translate services).

I don't know what is the best way to do this. I thought on create a private bower package with the coreapp and load it in the other projects.
I also want that the development process will be much confortable as possible.

Is there any better idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. There will be only one main module per application.
2. You can create sub modules based on the parent module.
3. I don't think you can run sub modules in different domain, because of the fact that sub modules will loaded/instantiated after the main module.